# Why can one get rid of a conditioning sigma-algebra by independence by setting another sigma-measurable variable equal to a constant?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability, martingales

Let $X_1,X_2,...$ be iid $\sim$ Exp(1)

$M_n =\frac{n!}{(1+S_n)^{n+1}}e^{S_n}$ is a martingale with respect to the natural filtration $\mathcal F_n=\sigma(X_1,...,X_n)$

$S_n \sim$  Gamma$(n,1)$ and the pdf is $f_{X_n}(x)=\frac1 {(n-1)!}x^{n-1}e^{-x}1_{[0,\infty)}$

I have already proven that it is adapted and the expectation is finite. But I don't know how to proceed with the martingale property:

$$E[M_{n+1}|\mathcal F_n]= E[\frac{(n+1)!}{(1+S_{n+1})^{n+2}}e^{S_{n+1}}|\mathcal F_n]$$
$$=(n+1)!e^{S_n}E[\frac{1}{{(1+S_n+X_{n+1}})^{n+2}}e^{X_{n+1}}|\mathcal F_n]=?$$

I don't think I can use the pdf with that $\mathcal F_n$ on the way. The only conditional expectation that I have seen how to compute explicitly are those of the form $E[X|\sigma(Y)]=E[X|Y]$ in  which case I need the conditional pdf: $f_{X|Y=y}(x)$, to find $h(y)=E[X|Y=y]$ and then $E[X|Y]=h(Y)$. But in this more abstract case how should I proceed?

My lecturer did this:

$$\mathbb{E} [ \frac{1}{(1+S_n+X_{n+1})^{n+2}} e^{X_{n+1}}  |\mathcal{F}_n ] = f(S_n) $$

with

$$f(s) := \mathbb{E} [ \frac{1}{(1+s+X_{n+1})^{n+2}} e^{X_{n+1}} ], \qquad s \geq 0$$

arguing that the $(X_k), k \in \mathbb{N}$ are independent, so $X_{n+1}$ is independent from $\mathcal{F}_n$ and $S_n$ is $\mathcal{F}_n$-measurable

But I am not convinced of this. If I compute $f(s)$ I think $f(S_n)$ would be just :
$$ f(S_n)=\mathbb{E} [ \frac{1}{(1+S_n+X_{n+1})^{n+2}} e^{X_{n+1}}   ]  $$

so no conditioning which is not the original expression.

I know that I can get rid of the conditioning when there is independence and that measurable function with respect to the conditioning sigma algebra can be taken out of the expectation, but in this case why is it true? Can you provide additional examples of this trick?

Comment: Let $g(X,Y)\in L^1$ with $Y\in\mathcal F$ and $X$ independent of $\mathcal F$. Then $E(g(X,Y)\mid\mathcal F)=f(Y)$ where $f(y)=E(g(X,y))$. A proof can be found in any probability text.

Comment: @AndrewZhang do you know of any one in specific with this particular property? I am using Williams: Probability with martingales and it is not there.

Comment: I personally learned from Durrett. The result actually holds more generally even if $X$ is not independent, but then one needs to replace $X$ with $U$ in the definition of $f(y)$ where $U$ has the regular conditional distribution of $X$ given $\mathcal F$. Not sure of a reference for this of the top of my head, maybe Kalleberg or Dudley?